# How to save a global variable with table format from NetLogo Behaviorspace

Tags: global-variables, netlogo, behaviorspace

I have written a fairly complicated code for my ABM (634 agents having interactions, each having different variables some of which are lists with multiple values that are updated each tick). As I need to save the updated values for all agents, I have defined a global variable using table:make. This table has 634 keys (each key for one agent), and each key has a list of those values (from that agents-own list variable) for the correspondent agent. But when I use the name of this table to be reported as one of my outputs in Behavior Space, the result in csv file is a table with no keys and it has only a number in it: {{table: 1296}}. So, I was wondering how I could change this variable to be able to have all values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're happy to do some post-processing with R or something after the fact, then `table:to-list` might be all you need. For example, with a simple setup example like:

```
extensions [ table ]

globals [ example-table ]

turtles-own [ turtle-list ]

to setup
  ca
  crt 3 [
    set turtle-list ( list random 10 one-of [ "A" "B" "C" ] random 100 )
  ]
  set example-table table:make
  foreach sort turtles [
    t ->
    table:put example-table ( word "turtle_" [who] of t ) [turtle-list] of t
  ]
  reset-ticks
end
```

And a `to-report` to clean each table item such that the first item is the key and all other items are the items in the list:

```
to-report easier-read-table [ table_ ]
  let out []
  foreach table:to-list table_ [ i -> 
    set out lput ( reduce sentence i ) out
  ]
  report out
end
```

You can set up your BehaviorSpace experiment such that one of your reporters is that reporter, something like:

[image]

To get a .csv file like:

[image]

Where the reporter column outputs a list of lists that you can process how you like.

*However*, I probably wouldn't use the basic BehaviorSpace output for this, but instead have a call in the experiment to call a manual table output procedure. For example, using the `csv` extension to make this `output-table` procedure:

```
to output-table [ filename_ table_ ]
  let out [["key" "col1" "col2" "col3"]]
  foreach table:to-list table_ [ i ->
    set out lput ( reduce sentence i ) out
  ]
  csv:to-file filename_ out
end
```

This outputs a much more analysis-ready table if you're less comfortable cleaning the output of a list-of-lists that as far as I know is what you would get from the BehaviorSpace output. So, you can either call it at the end of your experiment, like:

[image]

To get a table like:

[image]

Which is a little nicer to deal with. You can obviously modify this to report more often if needed, for example:

[image]

which would output a table at each tick of the experiment (you can also do this in your code to make it a little easier).

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive answer. Although, as there are 634 agents and each of their variables has 37 members, the maximum limit to put numbers in a line is exceeded and the results are shown in multiple lines. Plus, since there are 4 tables defined for all agent with this condition, I don't know whether there will be a problem using R to analyze them or not.

Comment: @user3918211 - Interesting. Does it work with the second approach? I don't think that 37 variables + the key should be too much for the csv to output.

Comment: Yes! When I check it with another software like Textpad, it shows data perfectly, but when I open it with Excel or Notepad, this problem exists! Plus, the number of output columns for my model is around 87500 (28 variables, some of which having data for 634 agents and for all 37 sub-categories [634*37=23458 columns for one variable]). And, as I haven't started learning and working with R, I am afraid I spend so much time running the model and the output wouldn't be useful.

Comment: @user3918211 - Sounds like a tough nut to crack! I would recommend trying to format your output so that all variables other than your tables are output using the normal BehaviorSpace tables, and then that you manually output the 4 table variables (either into individual files or combine them into a single list before output)- that should make your data far more manageable for analysis.